# Call an external tool from XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon, pandoc

I am processing XML document using XSLT (XSLT 2, Saxon B 9.1.0.8), producing HTML output. I want to support a tag

```
<markdown>
   This is some `markdown` text
</markdown>
```

with the semantics that the content of the tag (which should be parsed as-is, similar to a `<pre>` tag) would be filtered through `pandoc -f markdown -t html`.

How can I do that from an XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.html + https://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/ or plain external process call

Answer (score 3):

Saxon supports a number of mechanisms for writing extension functions, documented at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility

This is all described in terms of calling Java methods. There's no direct support for doing an exec of a shell command. You would want to write a Java wrapper around java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec() library method to capture the output into a string so that you can return the string result.

Comment: I’m currently using the `saxonb-xslt` command line tool. Your answer suggests that I’d have to replace that by custom Java code, right?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner - The extension function (java wrapper to execute pandoc) would be the only custom java code. However, you might need to use Saxon-PE or EE instead of saxonb-xslt. It's been so long since saxon-b/saxon-sa changed to HE/PE/EE, I can't remember if extension functions were supported in b.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I’m bound to use only free software (i.e. what’s in Debian). I guess I can solve it using a non-XSLT-preprocessing step more easily.

Comment: I don't know what the saxonb-xslt command line tool is, but the name would suggest it invokes Saxon-B, which is a fairly old product now, but it does allow calling out to Java.